# How to align a Grid to a Face in Geometry Nodes?

Tags: geometry-nodes

I want to instance a bunch of small objects to a grid, where the grid is aligned to a specific face.  What is the best way to achieve this?

I want to align the grid to the green X. This is what I've got so far:

[image]

[PROJECT FILE](https://www.dropbox.com/scl/fi/fdflpsx82v4ay0zewwj35/GN-Align-Grid-To-Face.blend?rlkey=203rhsjyjg5kp8o0m66mu9285&dl=0)

Ultimately what I'd like to do is be able to align my grid onto faces of objects with more complexity. For instance:

[image]

Comment: That can be a tesselation. But what the grid is supposed to look like if the face is a triangle?

Comment: That kind of thing? https://i.stack.imgur.com/bulTo.png

Comment: Crantisz recently reminded me of this [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=BKorP55Aqvg), might become my favorite thing to link under questions: wanting to put a square grid on a triangle sounds like wanting to have 3 perpendicular lines in a 2D space.

Comment: @lemon I love that solution in the image you sent, and although it isn't what I'm looking to do at this time, I would love to see the setup for how to achieve that

Comment: @MarkusvonBroady My question is strictly based on how to align things to other things in geonodes (i.e. a grid to a face), not how to fit a square into a triangle.  Apologies for any confusion, the answer below nailed it for me.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

*(Using Blender 3.6.5)*

Just to centre and align the grid to a face, you can proceed like this:
[image: GN graph]

**1.** Use a *Transform Geometry* node to move and rotate the grid, not a *Set Position* node that is affecting the vertices coordinates one by one.
**2.** Get the centre of the targetted face using a *Sample Index* node set to *Face* domain and input the *Position* as value.
**3.** Proceed the same for the normal, then convert the normal direction to rotation using a *Align Euler to Vector* node. The Z axis is chosen because it is the grid original normal.
**4.** For the demo, a constant input is used to choose a face index.

Comment: Thank you for this!  I absolutely cannot thank you enough, I have been banging my head against the computer all weekend.  The clincher for me is the Sample Index node which I did know about before and has profoundly expanded my knowledge and ability.  Cheers!

Comment: You are welcome. Happy New Year !